# setwidth of a dynamic textview

Tags: android

Actually my code is:

```
   LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);

    ll.setId(i);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    ll.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 5);
    //ll.setClickable(false);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);                   
    tv.setWidth(5);
    tv.setId(++i);
    tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    final TextView name = new TextView(this);
    name.setText(user_chat.get(j).toString()); 

    name.setWidth(60);
    name.setId(++i);
    //name.setClickable(false);   
    name.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    Log.v("TextView name",""+name.getText());

    TextView msg = new TextView(this);
    msg.setText(user_chat.get(++j).toString());                 
    msg.setWidth(100);
    msg.setId(++i);
    //msg.setClickable(false);        
    msg.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView time= new TextView(this);
    time.setText(user_chat.get(++j).toString());    
    time.setId(++i);
    //time.setClickable(false);        
    time.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ll.addView(tv);
    ll.addView(name);
    ll.addView(msg);
    ll.addView(time);                   
    lay.addView(ll);
```

In this name,msg,time text fields I am displyed.I want name msg and time in proper order I mean same line. But the width is not adjusted to both android and droid. What can I do?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess by "adjust to both droid and android" you mean "adjust to large-screen Android devices such as Motorola Droid, and to earlier normal-screen Android devices such as the Hero or G1".

I strongly suggest you read this article about how different screen sizes work in Android, and the notion of Device-Independent Pixels (DIPs):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

In your case I believe the information you seek can be found under section *3. Do not use hard-coded pixel values in your code .. Converting from DIPs to pixels.*

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not using the third parameter while setting the layout params?
constructor for this goes like this...

```
public LinearLayout.LayoutParams (int width, int height, float weight);
```

eg:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f));
```

You can set the third parameter to 1.0